# Where is the BERT log in linux located?

Tags: linux, logs

Fatal errors are recorded into BERT logs. BERT reports fatal errors that are resulted from surprise system reset or shutdown before OS had the chance to see the error. I think BERT stands for Boot Error Record Table.

Wanted to know where can I find the BERT log in linux ? I am unable to find it under /var/logs directory.

I am unable to find any information regarding BERT logs, any inputs would be very helpful.

> Under normal circumstances, when a hardware error occurs, kernel will
> be notified via NMI, MCE or some other method, then kernel will
> process the error condition, report it, and recover it if possible.
> But sometime, the situation is so bad, so that firmware may choose to
> reset directly without notifying Linux kernel.

> Linux kernel can use the Boot Error Record Table (BERT) to get the
> un-notified hardware errors that occurred in a previous boot.

Link to the source : https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-acpi/patch/13e567e22ba4776893cf074117d32e3c3276acb5.1467225769.git.tony.luck@intel.com/

Edit : Basically only after rebooting the system, the errors of previous boot would get logged into BERT, I think. I have edited the question and added the source from where I got the info about BERT log.

Comment: I've never heard of BERT logs before. How do you imagine the OS should write information to logs about events it didn't have a chance to see (from your own description).

Comment: I'm not sure if the OS creates the BERT log, but ACPI contains BERT table, which is supported in Linux. I have seen users on the internet posting BERT error logs, but was unable to find out the location of the log.

Comment: Basically only after rebooting the system, the errors of previous boot would get logged into BERT i think. I have edited the question and added the source from where I got the info about BERT log.

Comment: I've never seen a BERT error log myself, but a quick google search suggests that it should show up in the kernel log (i.e. output of `dmesg` or `journalctl -k` or in `/var/log/kern.log`) the next time the system boots.  I'm not sure whether that happens automatically, or if you need to be running some kind of daemon to enable it.